# Powershell equivalent to Azure CLI "az vm run-command invoke"?

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I have searched around to execute commands on my Linux VM via Powershell on my Windows laptop. I found that there is Azure CLI command `az vm run-command invoke` to invoke a command.

All I found in powershell is `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand` which takes a "script file path" (that means I have to find a way to upload the script file to VM first! what a hassle!) instead of putting direct commands.

Is there a `az vm run-command invoke` equivalent command in Powershell?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to put a direct command in the Azure PowerShell command to execute in the VM?

Comment: Yes. I want to put shell command in Powershell. The Powershell will communicate with my Azure Linux VM to execute that command in the VM. The use case is that I want to change some initial setting of my Linux VM (such as ssh listening port, mount Azure Storage) without installing Azure CLI.

Comment: So you can take a look at this command [Set-AzureRmVMExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/Set-AzureRmVMExtension?view=azurermps-6.5.0). And the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-automate-vm-deployment#automate-iis-install).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesXu-MSFT It seems to be what I need. I might have come across that command when I did my research, it's just that the document description is quite confusing -- in the overview section, it is talking about a script file will be download to execute while in the example it is executing a command directly. I will try that Set-AzureRmVMExtension.

Comment: That's great. If you tried and it works well. Please let me know.

Comment: I tried it with the following command to create a directorys but it seems stuck :

`Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ExtensionName "IIS" -VMName $VMName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation -Publisher Microsoft.Compute -ExtensionType CustomScriptExtension -TypeHandlerVersion 1.8 -SettingString '{"commandToExecute":"sudo mkdir -p /media/storage"}' `

I can not find any document about that ExtensionName parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the result, I misunderstood the command Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand . In the command Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand the parameter ScriptPath is actually a local file -- not the file uploaded on VM.

So that what I can do is to put all my bash scripts in the file system_setup.sh at the same directory as my Powershell and call the following command :

Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName -CommandId 
'RunShellScript' -ScriptPath '.\system_setup.sh'

Then Azure will upload and execute this shell script on the remote Linux VM as user root (not the ssh user set for VM) under the directory /var/lib/waagent/run-command/download/0

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PowerShell section of this Microsoft documentation page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#powershell

Here is a simple one I ran:

```
$resource_name="myVM"
$resource_group="myRG"
az vm run-command invoke -g "${resource_group}" -n "${resource_name}" --command-id 
RunPowerShellScript' --scripts "Write-Output 'testing russ'"
```

The output was:

```
{  "additionalProperties": {},  "endTime": "2018-07-25T00:09:42.479247+00:00",  error": null,  "name": "2a535b1a-e561-4a62-af43-c3c5c279bbcd",  "output": [    {      code": "ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded",      "displayStatus": "Provisioning ucceeded",      level": "Info",      "message": "testing russ"    },    {      "code": ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded",      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",      level": "Info",      "message": ""    }  ],  "startTime": "2018-07-5T00:09:09.605015+00:00",  "status": "Succeeded"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi RuSs, thanks for your reply but I am looking for the powershell version of your answer. I know "Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand" is similar to "az vm run-command invoke" but if you check it closely, you will find that "Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand" take only a script FILE while "az vm run-command invoke" can have direct command in it. So that it's not equivalent.